# How to keep good aspect ratio in parallel view

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I'm currently working on a STL file viewer which provides two types of views.

A perspective view (it's working perfectly):

[image: Perspective view]

and a parallel view (light calculation having trouble on this one but it's not the subject):

[image: Parallel view]

As you can see the parallel view is deformed. Here is how I calculate the view matrix:

```
float distance = glm::distance(focus,transform.GetPosition())* (ScreenSize.cx/ScreenSize.cy);
float distanceY = glm::distance(focus,transform.GetPosition())* (ScreenSize.cy/ScreenSize.cx);
return glm::ortho(-distance ,distance ,-distanceY ,distanceY, 0.00001f, 10000.0f);
```

I must explain a bit this code:

- **focus** is the central point of the model I'm viewing (0 0 0)
- **transform.GetPosition()** return the actual position of the camera
- **glm::distance(...)** return the length between both vector ( the camera vector can zoom or dezoom to the focus point)

My idea to avoid distortion was to get the screenSize of my actual ratio of my OpenGL context (stored in **ScreenSize**)  and multiply my distance with it in order to keep the rabbit unchanged whatever the screensize is. But it's not working, the rabbit are still stretched or crushed.

**how could I prevent my 3D model to get distorted whatever the screensize is on a parallel view ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete one of the screen size bits? Right now, if your window is 3/4 as tall as it is wide, then you're making the height 3/4 as tall (so far so good) *but* you're also making the width 4/3 as wide. You need to do one or the other, but not both.

Most computer games seem to keep the height the same - so the vertical view distance is always 1 (for example) - and adjust the width:

```
float distance = glm::distance(focus,transform.GetPosition())*(ScreenSize.cx/ScreenSize.cy);
//                                           delete this part vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
float distanceY = glm::distance(focus,transform.GetPosition())*(ScreenSize.cy/ScreenSize.cx);
```